# Convergence rate of inverse power method (without shift)

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

In class we learned about convergence rate of the `Power Method`, which is

$$\kappa = \frac{|\lambda_2|}{|\lambda_1|}$$

if $|\lambda_1| > |\lambda_2| \geq |\lambda_3| ...$ $and$ $\lambda_1$ has a `algebraic multiplicity` of 1.

Now an exercise wants us to discuss the convergence rate of a matrix with the `Inverse Power Method` (without `shift`).
I only found this formula for convergence rate for the `Inverse Power Method with shift` $\widetilde{\lambda}$:

$$\kappa = \frac{|\lambda_1 - \widetilde{\lambda}|}{|\lambda_2 - \widetilde{\lambda}|}$$

with $\lambda_1$ being the closest eigenvalue (of `A`?) to $\widetilde{\lambda}$ and $\lambda_2$ the second-closest eigenvalue to $\widetilde{\lambda}$.

So what is the convergence rate of the `Inverse Power Method without shift`?

Comment: Without shift just means that $\tilde λ=0$, everything else stays the same.

Comment: @LutzL So what would $\lambda_1$ be? The smallest eigenvalue of $A$ and $\lambda_2$ the second-smallest?

Comment: Yes, measured in absolute value. Or you could reduce the problem and its analysis to finding the largest eigenvalue of $A^{-1}$.